# change some attribute in java bean in session

Tags: java, spring, session

I have a java bean in a session and I did this:

```
QuestionnaireBeanWrapper wrapper = ( QuestionnaireBeanWrapper ) session.getAttribute( examPart );
wrapper.getQuestionnaireBeanList().get( examNumber - 1 ).setQuestionAnswer( examAnswer );
```

I change an attribute in the `bean`. My question is should I set it again in the `session`? or the object in the `session` is changed automatically?

Comment: Yes, it will changed automatically as you cnaged is [by reference][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve the bean from session you have a reference to the bean.  When a change is made on the bean through the reference the changes will be reflected in session since it points to the same object.

Try the following example:

```
QuestionnaireBeanWrapper wrapper = 
    ( QuestionnaireBeanWrapper ) session.getAttribute( examPart );
wrapper.getQuestionnaireBeanList().get( examNumber - 1 ).setQuestionAnswer( examAnswer );

QuestionnaireBeanWrapper wrapper2 = ( QuestionnaireBeanWrapper ) session.getAttribute( examPart );
System.out.println(( wrapper.getQuestionnaireBeanList().get( examNumber - 1 ).getQuestionAnswer() ==  wrapper2.getQuestionnaireBeanList().get( examNumber - 1 ).getQuestionAnswer())? "Same":"Different");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will changed automatically as you changed is by reference.
See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).